# Namespace or Package Resolution in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, module, namespaces, checkout

I have a local Objective-C class Card.h in my Bridging-Header.h and I am using CheckOutKit that also have a class Card.h. CheckoutKit is in swift.

In my ViewController.Swift I want to create a

```
var card : CheckoutKit.Card? = nil
```

But its not accessing. I have turned on Modules in project settings, also I have imported CheckoutKit as module.

```
import Foundation
import CheckoutKit

@objc public class PaymentsViewController:UIViewControlle
{
  var ck: CheckoutKit? = nil
  ** var card : CheckoutKit.Card? = nil
}
```

Also just noticed CheckoutKit have a class with same name CheckoutKit.Swift, so when I refer to CheckoutKit.Card compiler is referring to CheckoutKit's Card type which is not there.

On ** line this is error message

```
'Card' is not a member type of 'CheckoutKit'
```

Comment: don't post images for the code , instead you can use post the code directly

Comment: image is here to show error message and place of occurrence and not the code.

Comment: I know but the image is not clear so that copy and paste the error in question

Comment: Even if the image was clear... **always post code**. You can *also* post an image of the errors if you want, but you should never post just an image. Thanks.

Comment: Related to your issue: are you sure that `Card` is defined inside the `CheckoutKit` module? Isn't it just `Card` and not `CheckoutKit.Card`?

Comment: After abstracting Card.h that belongs to my own card still I am getting same error. It means issue is with module and class name as i wrote in last two lines.